Is there a way of detecting if a person is on escalator or not?
Im doing a project to detect whether a person stepped on to the escalator or not.
What I have tried:
I used android sensor data (linear accelerator) to detect if a person is walking, stopped or on an escalator. I have normalized x,y,z in a formula like this: sqrt(x^2+y^2+z^2), then group them into 64 and covert into fft data then trained on decision tree algorithm.
It worked well on detecting id a person is walking but it has lot of errors when a person is stopped or a phone is moved fast.
would there be any other sensor data that I can use? or is there any other way that I can approach?
